# Checkout Page Hacked?

Tags: checkout, security

I hope someone can help.

Running Magento 1.9.1.0, website. When a customer click  at checkout page sudden there is a strange customer information and payment information popup.But I don't find this file in cpanel file manager.
Any ideas what this might be and how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.
[firs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdYbM.png)[image]

Answer (score 1):

This one very dangerous. Verify this immediately https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-fix-credit-card-hijack/